# Unable to set reference variable in recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I am using a recursive method to find a node in a binary tree using a key. When I find the node, I set it to my reference variable `foundNode` and return. The problem is that when I read the object its value is still `null`. Can anybody help?

```
findGivenNode(root, key, foundNode, parentStack);

private boolean findGivenNode(Node node, int key, Node foundNode, Stack<Node> parentStack) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }

    parentStack.add(node);
    if (node.getData() == key) {
        foundNode = node;
        return true;
    }  
    boolean leftReturn = findGivenNode(node.getLeftChild(), key, foundNode, parentStack);
    boolean RightReturn = findGivenNode(node.getRightChild(), key, foundNode, parentStack);        
    if (leftReturn || RightReturn) {
        return true;
    }  else {
        parentStack.pop();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't pass arguments by reference, they are passed by value. [Read more here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

Let's clarify by an example. Make the key you are looking for be integer with value `21`.
The situation at the beginning of the function is the following:

[image: initial_state]

So now, when you say:

```
foundNode = node; // this doesn't reflect outside of the method
```

You are changing the value of `foundNode` locally inside the `findGivenNode()` method, it doesn't apply to outside this method. Basically, the local variable called `foundNode` references the node you want to change and then you make this local variable `foundNode` reference the new node by the statement above. 
This change is reflected only inside the function. As soon as your function is finished, local variables don't exist anymore so neither does this local version of `foundNode`. Visual result:

[image: wrong_move]

The simple solution is to use a [**`Wrapper function`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Wrapper_function)

To keep track of the reference, you can make a simple wrapper class that will store the reference you want:

```
private class NodeWrapper {
    Node foundNode;
    NodeWrapper() {
        foundNode = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a new `NodeWrapper` and pass that into your function instead of `foundNode`

```
NodeWrapper wrapper = new NodeWrapper();
findGivenNode(root, wrapper, key, parentStack);
```

Then inside your function instead of:

```
foundNode = node;
```

You say:

```
wrapper.foundNode = node;
```

This way you can maintain the reference throughout the recursion inside the `NodeWrapper`. Meaning:

```
NodeWrapper wrapper = new NodeWrapper();
findGivenNode(root, wrapper, key, parentStack);
// at this point, wrapper.foundNode will hold the reference to the node you need
// or null if the node wasn't found
```

On another note, above the method you have this function prototype:

```
findGivenNode(root, key, foundNode, parentStack);
```

Seems like someone is still used to C/C++ :)

This is unnecessary in Java, you can read [**this question thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032327/why-does-c-need-prototype-functions-while-java-does-not) for reasoning behind that or just Google it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but by setting (foundNode = node) I am trying to get the reference of the node that has the key and not the node itself. Secondly, foundNode is just a reference variable so can't set the value by calling any of the setter methods.

Comment: To the secondly part, Yes it can. `foundNode` points to the node you want to change so it has access to the methods of that node.

Comment: But changing the node is not the point of setting the reference variable to that node. All I need is a reference to that node. which I am not getting unless I do something like `foundNode = node; return foundNode;` And change the method's return type from `void` to `Node`.